# Cant run migrations in UWP app

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, uwp, entity-framework-core

Ive been dealing with this for a few days and Im driving crazy here. I created a uwp project that uses SQLite and EF Core to handle database layer and I had to add more columns to the entities I created at the beginning. I used Code-First approach and I was able to run my first migration (created the Migrations folder with the migration class and the snapshot). But when I try to run the 'Add-Migrations SecondMigration' command I get the following error.

**PM>  Add-Migration MigrationPk
To undo this action, use Remove-Migration.
Add-Migration : Cannot add the link because the source file '' cannot be found.
At line:1 char:2
+  Add-Migration MigrationPk
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Add-Migration], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException,Add-Migration**

I have installed the following:

```
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite": "1.1.2",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.1",
"Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform": "5.2.2"
```

And I have the following project structure:

-UWP project (using PRISM framework)
-DAL class library project
-LogicUI class library (view models)
-Utils class library project
-Test projects

I also tried to run the 'Add-Migration' command by using the context, project, and startProject as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell

I also uninstalled and installed again EF core without any luck

Any ideas? Thanks guys!

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue on my side, I can create a second migration successfully. I'm using Visual Studio 2017, UWP app target 15063. So please provide more information to let us help you narrow the issue. For example, the environments. And did your project set to X86? Did you have  correct `DbContext` for migration? Could you please create a blank UWP app on your side with [this simple demo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/uwp/getting-started) to see if it works?

Comment: hey I noticed that I had the name of the DB set to a constant, as soon as I set the name directly without the constant the migrations started to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue was that I had the db name in a constant. When I moved away from there and "hardcoded" in the dbcontext the migrations started to work